# Connect to a wireless router through LAN instead of via wi-fi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have a internet connection on my laptop which is provided by a router(let's call it router 1), so my laptop is connected to the LAN of router 1. There is a wireless router which is also connected to the same LAN and uses the internet connection provided by it, let's call this router router 2.

Just to be clear both my laptop and router 2 are connected to router 1 via ethernet cable and router 1 provides internet connection to both my laptop and router 2.

All the devices connected to router 1 have to use their own static ip to connect to the internet. And the speed of the internet connections are limited.

The internet speed that router 2 gets through this internet connection is much higher than my laptop's connection's speed limit. So I am trying to connect to router 2 to access the internet.

I know the password for the internet connection that router 2 provides. I also have administrative access to router 2 which I can connect through the LAN of router 1.

But the problem is my laptop is not in the range of the wireless network provided by router 2 and it's not possible for me to get my laptop to its range either.

So is there any way I can use the internet connection of router 2 from my laptop.(The only way I can connect to router 2 is through the LAN provided by router 1)

Comment: brain a bit crossed reading through your description... just to confirm... which router has internet access?

Comment: router 1 is the main internet provider. And both my laptop and router 2 connects to router 1 via ethernet cable to get internet access and router 2 shares this internet via wi-fi.

Comment: Based on your confirmation... anything connected to Router1 (in this case your laptop via LAN) - should have the fastest internet connection. If you are experiencing faster internet connection when connected over wifi (and via Router2 which internet access requires going via Router1) - then you have some weird settings that make your internet slower when connected via Router1.

Comment: Router 1 restricts the internet speed of the devices according the ip the device uses to connect to the router. And for each ip provided by router 1, only one device with a specific mac-id can connect to it. And router 1 provides fast internet connection to the ip that router 2 uses to connect to router 1 and I can't use that ip address. The connection router 1 provides to my laptop's ip is much slower.

Comment: So your options drops to: Having access to Router1 and change that setting, or somehow connect to Router2 (either wireless, or wired). Not much we can do to help.....

Comment: I am really confused about what you want. You want to make the internet connection via router 2(or Wi-Fi) to your laptop. This is opposite to the title of your problem. 

It is advisable for to simplify your problem and explain it clearly.

Comment: I do want use the internet connection provided by router 2. But, as I said in the question, my laptop is not in the wifi range provided by router 2. The only way I can connect to router 2 is through the LAN provided by router 1.